# Python __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, init, super

```
class Base:

    def __init__(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class A(Base):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x, y, *args, **kwargs)


class B(Base):

    def __init__(self, x, y, t, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x, y, *args, **kwargs)


class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z, t, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x, y, z, *args, **kwargs)


C(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
        C(1, 2, 3, 4)
    File "test.py", line 22, in __init__
        A.__init__(self, x, y, z, *args, **kwargs)
    File "test.py", line 10, in __init__
        super().__init__(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'
```

I first try to add '*args' and '**kwargs', but it didn't work. I wonder why this happen? How to fix? Could someone explain this for me? Thank you!

Comment: @blurfus C is inherit from A and B, I don't think that's the reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310777/18648900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are discarding `t` altogether; `*args` is empty when you call `C(1, 2, 3, 4)`; the value of the 4th parameter isn't automatically added to it, so `B.__init__` will never see it.

Likewise, `A.__init__` will cause `B.__init__` to only be called with 2 arguments, which is where the error comes from: no 3rd argument for `B.__init__`.

The ordering of positional parameters can be an issue as well; the standard advice is to use *keyword* arguments exclusively, and let each `__init__` extract the keyword arguments needed for its own parameters. For example,

```
class Base:

    def __init__(self, *, x, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class A(Base):

    def __init__(self, *, z, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.z = z


class B(Base):

    def __init__(self, *, t, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.t = t


class C(A, B):
    pass


C(x=1, y=2, z=3, t=4)
```

Now there is no ambiguity about which positional arguments are consumed by which `__init__` method: `A.__init__` gets `z` and leaves `x` ,`y`, and `t` for classes higher up the MRO to deal with. `B.__init__` extracts `t`, leaving `x` and `y`. `Base` extracts `x` and `y`, leaving nothing (as is correct) to be passed on to `object.__init__`.

(`Base.__init__` uses `super` as well, because you don't know what other class `Foo` might use `Base` in a way that `Base` will *not* be the last class in `Foo`'s MRO. Only `object.__init__` does not use `super()`; it's sole purpose is to terminate the chain of `super` calls, as there's nothing in a bare `object` instance to initialize.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally understand *, *args, **kwargs, super, and MRO.